# How to empty Cart After checking out or making Order?Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, e-commerce, cart

I have e commerce project,I need to empty cart after user checkout and order status is "shipped
also if I empty cart manually also orders already made be empty!
where is the problem in code and how to separate cart and orders made?

```py
def checkout_home(request):
  cart_obj, cart_created = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
  order_obj = None
  if cart_created or cart_obj.products.count() == 0:
      return redirect("cart:home")
  login_form = LoginForm()
  address_form = AddressForm()
  shipping_address_id = request.session.get("shipping_address_id", None)
  address_qs = None
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
      address_qs = Address.objects.filter(user=request.user)
  order_obj, order_obj_created = Order.objects.new_or_get(cart_obj=cart_obj,user=request.user)
  if shipping_address_id:
      order_obj.shipping_address = Address.objects.get(id=shipping_address_id)
      del request.session["shipping_address_id"]
      order_obj.save() 
  context = {
      "object": order_obj,
      # "billing_profile": billing_profile,
      "login_form": login_form, 
      "address_form": address_form,
      "address_qs": address_qs,}

  return render(request, "carts/checkout.html", context)
def checkout_done_view(request):
  Orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)
  return render(request, "carts/checkout-done.html",{"orders":Orders})
```

orders.models.py

```py
class OrderManager(models.Manager):
   def new_or_get(self, user, cart_obj):
       created = False
       qs = self.get_queryset().filter(
               user=user, 
               cart=cart_obj, 
               active=True, 
               status='created'
               )
       if qs.count() == 0:
           obj = self.model.objects.create(
           user=user, 
           cart=cart_obj)
           created = True

       else:
           obj = qs.first()

       return obj, created
class Order(models.Model):
   user             = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete='CASCADE',related_name="shipping_address",null=True, blank=True)
   # shipping_address_final    = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   order_id         = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
   cart             = models.OneToOneField(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   status           = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="created", choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOISES)
   shipping_total   = models.DecimalField(default=5.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
   total            = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
   active           = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   date_posted      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   objects = OrderManager()
```

cart.models.py:

```py
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs      = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj = False
            print('cart id exists')
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            print("new cart created")
            new_obj = True
            cart_obj= Cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj

    def new(self, user=None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)
class Cart(models.Model):

    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()
```

any one can help? I will appreciate any help thanks in advance..

Comment: error :b/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: orders_order.cart_id

Answer (score 0):

By setting `on_delete` argument to *cascade* you have instructed the database to delete related entry when that instance is deleted.

Remove that functionality from the cart foreign key in your Order model:

```
cart = models.OneToOneField(Cart, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

You should migrate your database afterward with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I got that error:cart     = models.OneToOneField(Cart)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Comment: Yep, no default value, sorry, forgot that, I edited my answer.

Comment: still not working, the issue is when i try to empty cart also orders be empty

Comment: That's on the database level, you should make migrations and migrate your database.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a BooleanField to your cart: "is_current" and set it to True by default when a product is added.
When your customer place an order, you can switch the cart item attribute "is_current" to be False. That way you do not delete the link between your order and your cart.